# Simple Shared Library MacOS

Tags: macos, dylib

I am trying to create a shared library on the MAC using following the simple example at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/CreatingDynamicLibraries.html

I have really dumbed it down to one function to try to get a function exported by clang in a library. My source code is as follows:

```
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))

EXPORT
void foo(){
    int x = 1 + 3;  
}
```

my compile line is

```
clang -dynamiclib lib.c -current_version 1.0  -compatibility_version 1.0 -fvisibility=hidden -o lib.dylib
```

This compiles fine and produces lib.dylib on my macbook. Now I would expect the nm tool to show my foo() export but the foo method is not exposed

```
nm -gu lib.dylib
```

returns only

```
dyld_stub_binder
```

I have been banging my head against this for a day now and it make no sense. Does anyone know what is wrong with this approach.

Comment: I see you answered your own question, but why did you have the `-u` flag on `nm` to begin with?

Comment: It was not actually needed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that using nm does not output what I expected i found that calling the method actually works using these steps. I wrote another program that uses this library as a test in it works fine. Spent too much time not testing the solution correctly.